# UI Phone number accepting - international format

Tags: user-interface, phone-number

Are there any standards for phone number across the world.
I would like to create one UI to accept the phone number
Depending on country the phone number accepting dialog should be changed like in US it should be +1-408-567-9822
There are different such types of conventions getting followed across the world.
Are there any location to get all standards or code to format the phone numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard, [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164). There are libraries available for handling phone numbers, such as [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).

Comment: Which does not include +1-408-567-9822  - just numbers from the page as far as I can see.

Comment: That is why you should use a library for handling user input. E.164 might be useful for storing the phone numbers in a canonical form, but you should not expect users to input their phone numbers in that format.

Comment: but people will want to see it the way they entered it so you have to store that format. OK to send a E.164 to systems that don't display the number or to other systems the original user does not see,

Answer (score 1):

There are different formats in different countries e.g. my phone numbers in the UK are 020 8xx xxxx and 07963 xxx xxx but noit every one uses these formats for various reasons e.g. many write the first as 0208 xxx xxx and the latter as 0796 3xxx xxx also (020) 8xx xxx. And also if cutting and pastin you might have 0208xxxxxx

Thus my view is that there there is no satisfactory format just accept any sequence of numbers and characters and ignore the characters having the correct number of digits. I would choose the country separately so the +1 for America , +44 for UK so that you can dial locally if in the country, but the rest are just any numbers,

Comment: Amen to that! I hate software that scolds me for putting in or leaving out dashes, when the software is perfectly capable of stripping them out on its own.